# How to stop maven from checking for snapshot updates?

Tags: maven-2

From what I understand, in case of maven2, by default maven will check for snapshot updates once per day.

I've attempted to override it in settings.xml [[pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/GLwjG9KG)] by setting updatePolicy to never, but during `mvn clean install` it still checks for snaphots updates.

Maven output which lead me to believe it still checks updates:

```
[INFO] snapshot XXXXXXXX:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from apache.snapshots
```

Is there something wrong in my setting.xml configuration, or is there some other option? Make note that using RELEASE instead of SNAPSHOT is not an option. I'm aware that using -o as offline mode will work, but that will prevent me from getting new dependencies as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done this for `central` but the output above indicates reference to `apache.snapshots`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it for everything, e.g. put * instead of name?

Comment: @bbaja42. No. You should do it for each of your `repository` definitions as appropriate.